# Installation EasyAdmin on Symfony4

Tags: symfony, configuration, symfony4, easyadmin

I try to install EasyAdminBundle on fresh install of Symfony4 from this doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html

But I can't access to the back-end, I'm getting 404...

I just type `composer require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle`, and add my entity(Command) to framework.yaml

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #default_locale: en
    #csrf_protection: true
    #http_method_override: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: ~

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

    cache:
        # Put the unique name of your app here: the prefix seed
        # is used to compute stable namespaces for cache keys.
        #prefix_seed: your_vendor_name/app_name

        # The app cache caches to the filesystem by default.
        # Other options include:

        # Redis
        #app: cache.adapter.redis
        #default_redis_provider: redis://localhost

        # APCu (not recommended with heavy random-write workloads as memory fragmentation can cause perf issues)
        #app: cache.adapter.apcu

    easy_admin:
        entities:
            # change the following to the namespaces of your own entities
            - App\Entity\Command
```

When I check my routes with `php bin/console debug:router`

```
-------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  easyadmin                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/
  admin                      ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler_open_file        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

Could some one enlighten me ?
Be wrong on the first line of configuration is so frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've installed without problem easy-admin in one SF4 proyect. Try those steps:

In config/routes/easy_admin.yaml:

```
easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: '@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/AdminController.php'
    prefix: /admin
    type: annotation
```

In config/packages/easy_admin.yaml write (and delete it from framework.yaml):

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        - App\Entity\Command
```

When you install easy-admin you must have this line in your bundles.php file:

```
EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\EasyAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

On the other hand you have some yaml syntax error in your framework.yaml file.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't try your solution, I tried today.
I just fill the config/packages/easy_admin.yaml instead of framework.yaml and it works, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it help someone. I have same problem in symfony 4, check your `/public` directory, if missed  `.htaccess` install `composer require symfony/apache-pack` and try again `/admin`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html